# C++ vector - push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

In the C++ Primer book, Chapter (3), there is the following for-loop that resets the elements in the vector to zero.

```
vector<int> ivec; //UPDATE: vector declaration
for (vector<int>::size_type ix = 0; ix ! = ivec.size(); ++ix)
ivec[ix] = 0;
```

Is the for-loop really assigning `0` values to the elements, or do we have to use the `push_back` function?

So, is the following valid?

```
ivec[ix] = ix;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it? Because that would have answered your first question. If you actually write small programs to try such things you will learn *much* faster.

Comment: The primer is showing you looping. In practical terms there are faster ways to assign all the elements to 0.

Comment: The book mentions that `vector<int> ivec;` is an empty vector and subscripts can only be used to *fetch existing elements*

Answer (score 5):

> Is the for-loop really assigning 0
>   values to the elements? Or, we have to
>   use the push_back finction?

`ivec[ix] =0` updates the value of existing element in the vector, while `push_back` function adds new element to the vector!

> So, is the following valid?
>   ivec[ix] = ix;

It is perfectly valid **IF** `ix < ivec.size()`.

It would be even better if you use `iterator`, instead of index. Like this,

```
int ix = 0;
for(vector<int>::iterator it = ivec.begin() ; it != ivec.end(); ++it)
{ 
     *it = ix++; //or do whatever you want to do with "it" here!
}
```

Use of `iterator` with STL is idiomatic. Prefer iterator over index!

Comment: The change you propose certainly is better style and makes the code safer, but the above code does work, as long you really only increment `ix` by one in each iteration.

Comment: ... and nothing else messes with the vector. Yes, `!=` works, but why play with fire?

Comment: equally though if you change container type then < may not work. != is pretty idiomatic for coding dealing with iterators as the point is usually to seperate the algorithm from the data structure via iterators

Comment: @jk: *"!= is pretty idiomatic for coding dealing with iterators"*...if iterators. but the OP is using index, not iterator!

Comment: doh, yes - the whole snippet seemed a little strange as it would naturally be a std::fill but then it is an out of context pedagogic example

Comment: @Nawaz. But I think `ivec[ix] = ix;` is intented to add new values to the vector, and thus invalid, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: @user588855: No, `ivec[ix] = ix` doesn't add new value to the vector. It only updates the value at index `ix`. So yes, what you were thinking, is wrong. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the square brackets to retrieve and overwrite existing elements of a vector.  Note, however, that you cannot use the square brackets to insert a new element into a vector, and in fact indexing past the end of a vector leads to undefined behavior, often crashing the program outright.

To grow the vector, you can use the push_back, insert, resize, or assign functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the array brackets the vector object acts just like any other simple array.  `push_back()` increases its length by one element and sets the new/last one to your passed value.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this for loop is to iterate through the elements of the vector.
Starting at element x (when ix is 0) up to the last element (when ix is ivec.size() -1).

On each iteration the current element of the vector is set to 9.
This is what the statement

```
ivec[ix] = 0;
```

does. Putting

```
ivec[ix] = ix;
```

in the for loop would set all the elements of the vector to their position in the vector. i.e, the first element would have a value of zero (as vectors start indexing from 0), the second element would have a value of 1, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming ix is a valid index, most likely: you have a vector of int though and the index is size_type. Of course you may want to purposely store -1 sometimes to show an invalid index so the conversion of unsigned to signed would be appropriate but then I would suggest using a static_cast.

Doing what you are doing (setting each value in the vector to its index) is a way to create indexes of other collections. You then rearrange your vector sorting based on a predicte of the other collection.

Assuming that you never overflow (highly unlikely if your system is 32 bits or more) your conversion should work.